# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable (Python, Requests)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

While running script with one tax_id the output is given without any problem. But when I am adding multiple tax_ids this 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable' error message is appeared.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

url = 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/controller'

tax_ids = [
        '1306142621',
        '1403676911',
         ]

request_payloads = {"METHOD": "wsEbynGetDebetSum",
                    "voen": tax_ids,
                    }

with requests.Session() as s:
    for tax_id in tax_ids:
        request_payloads['voen'] = tax_id
        r = s.post(url, params=request_payloads)
        url_t = r.url
        response = requests.get(url_t)
        s = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
        output = s.text.strip()
        debt = re.search('"debet":"(.+?)"}}', output)
        if debt:
            m = debt.group(1)
            print([tax_id] + [m])
```

The error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "taxDebt.py", line 19, in <module>
    r = s.post(url, params=request_payloads)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
```

This line is overwriting your session variable declared here:

```
with requests.Session() as s
```

Change the `s = bs(...)` variable name to something else:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    for tax_id in tax_ids:
        request_payloads['voen'] = tax_id
        r = s.post(url, params=request_payloads)
        url_t = r.url
        response = requests.get(url_t)
        s1 = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
        output = s1.text.strip()
        debt = re.search('"debet":"(.+?)"}}', output)
        if debt:
            m = debt.group(1)
            print([tax_id] + [m])
```

Result:

```
['1306142621', '0.00']
['1403676911', '0.00']
```

Comment: the scraper is working too slow, i can not find the reason. Can you help me?